# how can i make print button that will print a report?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm doing on a project but my problem is that i don't have any idea on how to make a print button to print my report..the report is in a table..can somebody please help me with this one?my question is how can i add a button for printing?

here is my code for the viewing of specific record

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbconfig.php';
    $username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
    $password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';
    $province = isset($_GET['province']) ? $_GET['province'] : '';

    if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
    {
        $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
        extract($crud->getID($user_id));
    }
?>

<body>
<div id="Survey-view">
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <p><strong>INFORMATION</strong></p>
        <hr />
            <div id="main-frame">
                <table id="information-content" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                            <th>Province</th>
                        </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $password; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $province; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        <br />
    <br />
    <p><strong>ASP</strong></p>
        <hr />
            <div id="asp">
                <table id="asp-content" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date Survey</th>
                            <th>Date Submitted</th>
                            <th>Date Approved</th>
                            <th>Date Recv'd by Region</th>
                            <th>Date Recv'd by DARPO</th>
                        </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div><!-- End of asp-->
        <br />
    <br />
    <p><strong>DENR/DARPO</strong></p>
        <hr />
            <div id="denrdarpo">
                <table id="denrdarpo-content" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date Survey</th>
                            <th>Date Submitted</th>
                            <th>Date Approved</th>
                            <th>Date Recv'd by Region</th>
                            <th>Date Recv'd by DARPO</th>
                        </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div><!--End of denrdarpo-->
        <br />
    <br />
    <p><strong>OTHERS</strong></p>
    <hr />
    <div id="others">
        <table id="others-content" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Project Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
                <td>Module Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fund Year</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
                <td>LAD Target</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Land Category</td>
                <td><select disabled>
                        <option><?php echo $username; ?></option>
                    </select></td>
                <td>LAnd Type</td>
                <td><select disabled>
                        <option><?php echo $username; ?></option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date Reported</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
                <td>Date Suspended</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date Completed</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
                <td>Number of Lots</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Station</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
                <td>Contractor</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Agency</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
                <td>Cert 40</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: print client side or server side?

Comment: whi i do -- create a print specific format- redirect to that and use js to pop up the print dialoug

Comment: i know the idea but i don't know how?can you please help me?

Comment: what exactly is the problem then?

Comment: how is pdo relevant to printing the page?

Comment: the problem is that i dont know to do that print function?

Comment: @Adelphia there is no relevant i just stated it because maybe theres a pdo function for printing.

Comment: no sir, javascript is the only thing that can print a page. pdo is for connecting to a database and has nothing to do with the broswerr or your users' printers. i've given you the correct answer and a link to a working example. if that helps, please hit the checkmark next to the answer. @kier

Comment: @Adelphia i can't load the example page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time I need to do this I go to my old Gmail account, print a page and then view the source code cus I'm too lazy to remember the functions..

This is how Google does it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
document.body.onload=function(){document.body.offsetHeight;window.print()};
// ]]></script>
```

You could just as easily attach it to a button instead of doing it on load.

```
<button onclick="document.body.offsetHeight;window.print();">Print</button>
```

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2bsco49u/)

And this one will remove the button from the printed page:

```
<button onclick="this.style.display='none';document.body.offsetHeight;window.print();this.style.display='inline';">Print</button>
```

[And another example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2bsco49u/1/)

Comment: i can't open the example you posted..can you please help me edit my code above with a print..please..

Comment: @kier i'm not going to do all the work for you. all you have to do is copy the code for the button that i posted and add it to your html.

Comment: is that all i need to do?i just need to copy the code of you then it will print now?

Comment: why not test it @kier

Comment: only if you select my answer by hitting that check and give me an upvote. see, when you click the button, this code checks to see if you selected this answer and upvoted it, and if you did, then it will print the page. @kier

Comment: it worked! thanks..but there'e one problem the button is also showing in the print page

Comment: that's because you didn't select my answer. if you select it i will show you how to make the button go away when you press it. checkmark to your left. @kier

Comment: i'm sorry for that...can you please help me now with that?

Comment: you're smart..you want me first to press it as answer before you gave me the whole code..haha thank you very much..it worked now..

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin()
{
   var myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
   myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");

   myWindow.document.close();
   myWindow.focus(); 
   myWindow.print();
   myWindow.close();

 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: ok i removed the downvote since it's actually printing something now, but he wants to print the current page, not a new one.

Comment: @sandeepsure in your answer maybe i got some idea how it work but where do i put your answer in my code above?